# i lost external hard data after linux reinstall

Tags: hard-drive, backup, data-recovery

Linux reinstallation
mount the external hard

Reinstalling existing Linux (Pomeroy ago) nwatdeon data are transferred to external hard drive is not visible.

Disk space, the backup data will remain pointin state.

Can you see the problem is the file permissions after reinstallation is not reopened
How is there any way to recover?

```
df -h
```

78g used..

```
/dev/sdb1       917G   78G  793G   9% /mnt/sdb1


mount media/nas

ls -al "media/nas"
```

Invisible.

Comment: Are you talking about Ubuntu at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/dev/sdb1` device is mounted under the `/mnt/sdb1/` directory, so look in that directory to find your files. Maybe your previous linux installation had a setup to mount it under `/media/nas/` but now it is under `/mnt/sdb1/`.

If this wasn't your problem then please edit your question because it is almost impossible to get what is your problem.

Comment: thanks fix it ^^;;;
/etc/fstab /dev/sdb1 -> edit /media/nas
fix it so thankyou!